# String и char[]

Tags: java, строки

Я плотно занялся вопросом Core basics in Javа и, в частности, его методом `substring()`.
Насколько я понял, сам по себе объект типа `String` массивом `char`'ов не является, но метод `substring` оперирует именно массивом чаров созданного из нашего `String`. Можете пожалуйста рассказать схему того, когда именно создается этот массив? Где храниться? Или, по возможности, дайте пожалуйста ссылку на статью (сам в сети ничего не нашел).

Comment: > Я плотно занялся вопросом Core basics in Javа

Ох и скучное у вас занятие.

Лучше бы вы цель конкретно сказали. Там люди не один год писали и читали тоже:
Массив вот так определяется:

    /** The value is used for character storage. */
    private final char value[];

И вот так создаётся:

    this.value = Arrays.copyOf(value, size);

Answer (score 2):

Сам по себе, `String` - это класс, в котором как раз и лежит значение в виде массива `char`'ов.

Источник: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java

Вообще, конечно нехорошо лезть во внутренности реализации, но для самообразования сойдёт.

Comment: как раз для самообразования посмотреть реализацию внутри самое оно. После этого пропадает ощущение "магии", лучше понимается работа компилятора/языка, повышается качество кода.

Comment: @KoVadim, я как раз и имел ввиду, что вообще не хорошо завязываться на внутренней реализации, ибо завтра всё может поменяться. А смотреть хорошие примеры кода, это да, это нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Так ли иначе строка это "обертка" вокруг массива символов.
Когда создается строка поле offset устанавливается в 0, а массив символов заполнялся значениями. 
При вызове метода substring (а также Pattern.split) не нужно было реально выполнять копирования данных, достаточно было отдать объект у которого изменено значение поля offset.
Это ускоряет время работы, но оставляло место для утечек.

Но сейчас все вышеописанное уже не так. Поле offset больше не используется и строки между объектами не "шарятся", а происходит честное копирование.
Обсуждение изменений можно посмотреть тут http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/java/4988346

Последний вариант из OpenJDK можно посмотреть тут http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java